# Register Command in Discord.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, discord, discord.js

Can someone explain or pre-code a command in discord.js that puts a message of an author into the database?

For example:
User: !register
Bot: What username would you like to use? (in DMs)
User: Guest
Bot: *puts 'Guest' in TABLE accounts (name)*
Bot: What password would you like to use?
User: Password
Bot: *puts 'Password' in TABLE accounts (password)*
Bot: Your account has be **registered**!

I tried code from w3school but that didn't help me solve the problem.

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const mysql = require('mysql');
var con = connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'mapleorigins',
  charset : 'utf8mb4'
});

con.connect(err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to the database.")
})

bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online.`);
    bot.user.setGame("in development");
});

bot.on
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is not for us to code the command for you, but what you need to do is use a collector to collect the users messages after the command is registered. So your command would do the following;

- DM The user once command is run
- Ask user for username
- Collect username in collector
- Ask user for password
- collect password in collector
- Push user to database and return account created

Something that I **strongly recommend** is that you **hash the password**. Storing passwords in plain text is not wise at all, due to the fact that their is a chance that someone would enter the actual password that they use for other accounts. This then means when they login you would fetch the hash, then hash the password they entered and check that they match.